# Landscape behind proxy

Tags: landscape, reverse-proxy

I am trying to reach a landscape host (landscape1.domain.com, perfectly working) through a reverse-proxy (teleport actually: landscape1.teleport.domain.com), but it can't load css content (with a `(blocked:csp)` error) and all internal links point to landscape1.domain.com, so exiting from the proxy.

Is there a way to properly run landscape behind a proxy?

Thanks,